# jquery - while dragging an ordered list item, numbering of subsequent items always increases by 1

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

While the `jQuery sortable widget` works fine in most cases, in the case of an `ordered list`, the `numbering gets botched up when we drag an element`. The following is a sample program to illustrate this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <script src="jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('ol').sortable();
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <ol>
            <li>
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="name" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="class">Class</label>
                <input type="text" id="class" />
            </li>
        </ol>
    </body>

</html>
```

Before dragging :

[image]

During dragging :

[image]

The ordering gets restored once the drag is complete. This bug has been noted before but not fixed. Has anybody found a cure for this ?

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Rf7jw/) is the fiddle for it

Comment: If you create a jsFiddle (and upload/select the necessary ui library as a resource), probably more people would be willing to experiment and help immediately. Just a tip!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is caused by the `placeholder` of jquery UI which is automatically added to your list when sortable start. You can actually simply hide the placeholder on start event or create your own class which has display none.

Here the idea:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('ol').sortable({
        start: function( event, ui ){
            $(ui.item).parent().find('.ui-sortable-placeholder').hide();
        },
    });
});
```

Or:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('ol').sortable({placeholder: "sortable-placeholder"});
    });
</script>

<style>
    .sortable-placeholder {display: none;}
</style>
```

**EDIT:**

You can also actually set the placeholder display to block so that it is not assumed as a list child:

```
.sortable-placeholder {
    height: 20px;
    display: block;
}
```

Here modified [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Rf7jw/7/).

Comment: Thanks for that.. but doing this removes the element being dragged from the page.. and the dragging-over effect becomes a little ugly.. A fiddle showing the effect with your fix is http://jsfiddle.net/Rf7jw/1/ and the one without your fix is http://jsfiddle.net/Rf7jw/2/

Comment: @Daud just remember that you can set the placeholder to display as block to accomplish this. See my edited answer. Hope it helps.